# When does UB occur and does it nullify all previously engaged contracts?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior, memory-model

The C or C++ language semantics form a contrat with the user. Some constructs don't have any limit on their behavior, either by virtue of not having a specified behavior in some case (like dereferencing a pointer that doesn't point to an object, like a null pointer) or by being made *explicitly* undefined. In either case, no guarantee about the *following* behavior is provided.

But what about the past? These instructions that had defined behavior and produced output. I suppose the output can be erased, but the previous interactions could have been observed in the past.

Can undefined behavior be prescient such that some outputs do not occur? For example:

```
std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl; // with a flush
float f = 1./0.; // UB: cancels previous syscall?
```

Would not doing the `write` syscall (assuming Unix) be conforming here?

Now what about the memory model? There is a guarantee that all operations on an atomic object, on a mutex, and on all sequentially consistent operations each have an order (each one consistent with instruction flow, but their union doesn't have to be); when is that guarantee applied if the program exhibits undefined behavior?

Can an implementation use undefined behavior at some point in the program execution as an excuse to not ever respect the memory model requirements? In other words, **at which points can the client of the contract that is the language semantics (the user) expect these requirements (on I/O, on orders of operation) to be delivered?**

### Clarification: only well formed programs

(I realize that I may not have been as specific as I wanted.)

Some programs whose source code violate a consistency or soundness rule:

- violation of the one definition rule
- templates that have no valid specialization
- templates that bind to different names at different points

are described as being wholly invalid. These program can be rejected by the compiler with a diagnostic, or compiled, but in that case no execution of the program has defined behavior. Let's call that "*a priori* UB".

The question is not about those programs, but *about well formed programs that can have some well defined execution at least for some time.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194727/discussion-on-question-by-curiousguy-when-does-ub-occur-and-does-it-nullify-all).

Comment: [Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Answer (score 14):

> Can undefined behavior be prescient such that some outputs do not occur? For example: ... Would not doing the `write` syscall (assuming Unix) be conforming here?

Yes, it would be conforming. See [intro.execution]/5:

> A conforming implementation executing a well-formed program shall produce the same observable behavior as
>   one of the possible executions of the corresponding instance of the abstract machine with the same program
>   and the same input. However, if any such execution contains an undefined operation, this document places
>   no requirement on the implementation executing that program with that input (not even with regard to
>   operations preceding the first undefined operation).

Since your program contains *unconditional* UB, the standard imposes no requirements on the behaviour of the implementation *for any run of the program*.

Note that in cases where UB depends on input, such as:

```
int main() 
    double x;
    std::cout << "Please enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "The reciprocal of your number is: " << 1/x << std::endl;
};
```

the provision in [intro.execution]/7.3 applies:

> The input and output dynamics of interactive devices shall take place in such a fashion that prompting output is actually delivered before a program waits for input. What constitutes an interactive device is implementation-defined.

Thus, the program is not allowed to, say, wait for a nonzero value to be entered and only then print out the message `Please enter a number:`. It must print out the message first. So in this sense, the scope of UB is limited to events that occur *after the point where enough input has been entered to determine that the behaviour is undefined*.

Comment: Note that I posted a program fragment, not a complete program with `main`. The complete program may or may not run that fragment. (I should have made that more clear.)

Comment: @curiousguy take a look at the quote from [intro.execution] again. To paraphrase, if your program _possibly_ does an undefined operation for a given set of inputs, the **entire program's execution** has no behavioral requirements at all for those inputs. So if you can prove that your program never causes UB _for some given input X_, then your program must have conforming behavior _when it is given input X_. Otherwise, if your program is given some other input that causes it to perform UB _anywhere_, then _everything_ your program did, does, or will do is meaningless and without restriction.

Comment: @alterigel It seems like there is no concept of time in your C/C++ semantics? I/O is done over time. And the memory model uses orders; at which points are they defined? This seems like complete madness.

Comment: "_Since your program contains unconditional UB_" I don't think it's unconditional: consider the case of `cout` being tied to a file opened in blocking write mode, as after `dup2(open(name, O_WRONLY|O_APPEND|O_SYNC),1);`. The call to `std::cout << "hello, world" << std::endl;` should take as long as it takes to writes to long term storage. Completion of the call means that it's in long term storage, with the guarantees of durability of the file system and of Unix file semantics.

Comment: @curiousguy If there is a chance that the call will never complete, then I agree that the UB is conditional. If the call will always complete, but might simply take a long time, the UB is unconditional, and the compiler is allowed to do things like assuming that the code is unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

The Standard allows implementations to offer whatever behavioral guarantees they see fit beyond those that it mandates.  Given something like:

```
unsigned char ch = getc();
printf("Oh no %d\n", 1/ch + ((-ch)<<1));
```

the Standard does not recognize any situation in which execution could reach the `getc()` without also reaching the `printf`, and thus does impose any requirements upon program behavior should such a situation occur.  Implementations where such a situation could occur (e.g. because of a `SIGINT` triggered by control-C) that want to allow programmers to exploit the resulting semantics can and should offer appropriate guarantees beyond those mandated by the Standard, but the question of if and when to offer such guarantees falls outside the Standard's jurisdiction.